# aspnet mvc authenticate users using OAUTH2 custom provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jwt, adfs, asp.net-4.5, oauth-2.0

I have a MVC application that it's using local AD to authenticate users and get their Roles for set permissions to the application. Now I have a new requirement, I'll use an external AD to authenticate the users rather than the local one. So, my application will redirect users to the client's login page, users will enter username and password that will be validated on their AD and then redirect back to my application with a token. I need to get this token and post once again to the customer endpoint in order to get a JWT token.

The problem is that I could not find a good example of something similar to that. I was trying use Open Id:

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new 

OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                Authority = "https://xx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/adfs/oauth2/authorize",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:27100/token",
                ResponseType = "code",
                Scope = "openid email",
                Resource = "xxxxxxxx",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            });
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to create to obtain configuration from:
>   'https://xx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/adfs/oauth2/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration

If I open the full url on my local browser I can see the login page to the customer AD. I'm not sure if OpenIdAuthentication is the right one for this scenario, I was trying this one because is has all the properties that I need to set. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do an on-behalf of authentication?
Refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-on-behalf-of-authentication-in-windows-server-2016

For OpenID Connect with AD FS please refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openid-connect-with-ad-fs-2016

Answer (score 0):

The `.well-know/openid-configuration` endpoint should resolve to something that looks like:

[image]

You probably can just update the `Authority` property to one of these values (depending on where the STS is running):

- "https://xx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/adfs/"
- "https://xx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/adfs/oauth2"

Comment: both URL's are redirecting me to the login page. It seems that it set a cookie before redirect. I've sent an email to the customer asking for that endpoint.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use OpenId or if there's any other way